# ¿Cómo puedo evitar imprimir el último dato de una URL?

Tags: php

El siguiente código, me genera enlaces de categorías tomando el valor de la URL.

```
<?php
$trail = array(
   'path' => 'Cool Stuff',
   'to' => 'Animals',
   'a' => 'Spiders'
);

 $url = 'example.com/productos/belleza-mujer/perfume-de-mujer ';

$parts         = parse_url($url);
$path          = pathinfo($parts['path']);
$segments      = explode('/', trim($path['dirname'],'/'));

$breadcrumbs[] = '<a href="/">Home</a>';
$crumb_path    = '';

foreach ($segments as $segment) {
    $crumb_path .= '/' . $segment;

    $value = (array_key_exists($segment, $trail)) ? $trail[$segment] : ucfirst($segment);

    $breadcrumbs[] = '<a href="' . $crumb_path . '">' . ucwords(str_replace(['_', '-', '+'], ' ', $value)) . '</a>';
}

$breadcrumbs[] = ucwords(str_replace(['_', '-', '+'], ' ', 
$path['filename']));
$breadcrumbs   = implode(' &raquo; ', $breadcrumbs);

echo $breadcrumbs

?>
```

Cómo resultado me da la siguiente información:

> [Home](https://es.stackoverflow.com) » [Productos](https://es.stackoverflow.com) » [Belleza Mujer](https://es.stackoverflow.com) » Perfume de mujer

Pero que cambios se debe modificar o eliminar para tener un resultado de impresión de solo de categorías de esta manera:

> [Home](https://es.stackoverflow.com) » [Productos](https://es.stackoverflow.com) » [Belleza Mujer](https://es.stackoverflow.com)

O cómo evitó tomar el último valor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creo que te resultaría sencillo si eliminas el ultimo valor del arreglo que tienes antes de realizar el implode

```
$breadcrumbs   = implode(' &raquo; ', $breadcrumbs);
```

cambiar a

```
array_pop($breadcrumbs);
$breadcrumbs   = implode(' &raquo; ', $breadcrumbs);
```

Comment: Gracias amigo :)

Comment: De nada estimado! Fue un placer haberte ayudado!